# Execution Log with time filter is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, logging

I have an android mobile application in which "export diagnostic" button should execute Log command with the Logs tagged "DIAG_TAG", and then export it to txt file. Everything is going right till that point.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat $DIAG_TAG:* *:S -f $tempFile")
```

But I want to search from the logs that are created from the start of the application date which is saved in SharedPreferences - getAppLifecycleStartTime(). Unfortunately when I execute below code it generates empty file. So the time filter is not working correctly. The example time variable is like "05-17 15:15:32.000" What's wrong? The code:

```
    private fun executeDiagnosticLogs(tempFile: File) {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm:ss.mmm", Locale.getDefault())
        val appStartDate = sharedPreferenceManager.getAppLifecycleStartTime()
        val time = sdf.format(Date(appStartDate))
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat $DIAG_TAG:* *:S -T '$time' -f $tempFile")
    }
```